# What should I do when my question is not getting enough attention on the website it is most suitable for?

Tags: discussion, questions

I know that duplicating questions between communities is forbidden in a sense, but sometimes my question is not getting enough attention simply because the suitable Q&A website doesn't have big community such as SO.

What should I do in these situations?

- Delete the question in the site where is getting no attention and
  re-ask it in SO (and hopefully not get hated/downvoted for that,
  cause this is what happens usually).
- Simply wait for an answer that
  may took a lot of time.

Comment: Have you considered offering a [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)?

Comment: _"and hopefully not get hated/downvoted for that, cause this is what happens usually"_ Obviously, asking questions that are off-topic on SO is frowned upon. There are no exceptions related to not having enough attention or to having a smaller community where it belongs.

Comment: If you have followers on Twitter, tweet a link and maybe ask others to re-tweet. If you have other social media accounts, consider posting on those as well.

Comment: *hopefully not get hated/downvoted for that, cause this is what happens usually* - I don't think anyone is going to suggest that you should do this if you *know* it results in down votes. But in addition to existing suggestions, editing your question to improve it puts it at the top of "Active" questions.

Comment: I would just wait for a good answer, even though it may take some time. I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30412474/4284627) two years ago without getting any answer that worked, and today I finally got the answer I wanted. But if you need an answer fast, you might want to add a bounty. But please don't ask questions on sites where they're off-topic.

Comment: Note that there are circumstances where a question may be on-topic on multiple sites. In this case cross-posting is still disallowed, but you don't have to always pick "the most suitable site", if it is also on-topic for a higher traffic site that may be less "suitable" due to a broader scope, you _can_ pick that site. If you do post to the lower traffic site and find your question dormant then decide you would have rather posted the question on the higher traffic site, you should delete your question _then_ repost it. Again, make _sure_ it is on-topic on the target site first.

Comment: Why is everyone asking this question this week?

Comment: @xenteros It always seems to go that way. My guess on why this particular question is getting asked is because it's a time of year when people are on summer vacations and maybe traffic is down across the SE network in general. It's a wild guess though. (We'll likely get more homework and "SO is mean" type questions once we get a couple of weeks into the school year.)

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would do the following:

1. Wait until I can add a bounty to the question
2. Make my question as self explanatory as possible
3. Use external social media to promote my question
4. Engage in other questions so others would return the favor